# Detecting rows with multiple observations in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this. I want to recognize all of the observations that have multiple values in the "color" columns and replace them with "multicolor"

```
ID  color1   color2
23   red      NA
44   blue     purple
51   yellow   NA
59   green    orange
```

like this:

```
ID  color   
23   red      
44   multicolor     
51   yellow     
59   multicolor
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in the tidyverse.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("color"), values_to = "color", values_drop_na  = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(n = n(),
            color = toString(color), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(color = if_else(n > 1, "multicolor", color)) %>% 
  select(-n)

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#      ID color     
#   <int> <chr>     
# 1    23 red       
# 2    44 multicolor
# 3    51 yellow    
# 4    59 multicolor
```

I did it this way on purpose. Note that if you stopped after the `summarize()` line, you would get the actual colors.

```r
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      ID     n color        
#   <int> <int> <chr>        
# 1    23     1 red          
# 2    44     2 blue, purple 
# 3    51     1 yellow       
# 4    59     2 green, orange
```

This would scale if you had many color columns, not just 2. Play around with it, there are a lot of ways to tweaks things like this.

---

#### Data

```r
df <- read.table(textConnection("ID  color1   color2
23   red      NA
44   blue     purple
51   yellow   NA
59   green    orange"), header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, assuming `data` is your dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(ID = c(23, 44, 51, 59),
                   color1 = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green"),
                   color2 = c(NA, "purple", NA, "orange"))

data %>% 
  mutate(color = ifelse(is.na(color2), color1, "multicolor")) %>% 
  select(ID, color)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what seems like a straightforward solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
  mutate(
    # step 1 - paste `color1` and `color2` together and remove " NA":
    color = gsub("\\sNA", "", paste(color1, color2)),
    # step 2 - count the number of white space characters:
    color = str_count(color, " "),
    # step 3 - label `color` as "multicolor" where `color` != 0:
    color = ifelse(color == 0, color1, "multicolor")) %>%
  # remove the obsolete color columns: 
  select(-matches("\\d$"))
  ID      color
1 23        red
2 44 multicolor
3 51     yellow
4 59 multicolor
```

Data:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(23, 44, 51, 59),
                   color1 = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green"),
                   color2 = c(NA, "purple", NA, "orange"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A **base R** approach

```
# get colors from columns named color*
colo <- paste(names(table(unlist(df1[,grep("color",colnames(df1))]))), collapse="|")

colo
[1] "blue|green|red|yellow|orange|purple"

# match the colors and do the conversion
data.frame( 
  ID=df1$ID, 
  color=apply( df1, 1, function(x){ 
    y=x[grep(colo, x)];
    if(length(y)>1){y="multicolor"}; y } ) )
  ID      color
1 23        red
2 44 multicolor
3 51     yellow
4 59 multicolor
```

##### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(23L, 44L, 51L, 59L), color1 = c("red", 
"blue", "yellow", "green"), color2 = c(NA, "purple", NA, "orange"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```